# Regex for finding three difference file name patterns?

Tags: regex

```
/myFilename_.*csv|other_.*csv|third_.*/g
```

It almost works but matches a whole line when two matches are present ?

I am trying to find **myFilename_randomstuff.csv** *or* **other_5randomstuff.csv** *or* **third_randomstuff.csv**

http://regexr.com/3e6al

Comment: A basic regex tutorial may solve the problem.

Comment: Non-greedy matches - `myFilename_.*?csv|other_.*?csv|third_.*?.csv`

Answer (score 1):

```
myFilename_.*?\.csv.*?|other_.*?\.csv.*?|third_.*?\.csv.*?
```

Comment: Perhaps shorten to `myFilename_.*?\.csv|other_.*?\.csv|third_.*?\.csv` as anything can come after the `.csv` anyway and matching zero or more characters non-greedily is always going to match nothing. (Could this be marked as the accepted answer?)